# How to get combine value from array?

Tags: php, html, html-table

Array :

```
$result = [
    0 => [
        'day_date' => '2017-10-27',
        'phase' => 'Definition',
        'foodstyle' => null,
        'workout_id' => 9
    ],
    1 => [
        'day_date' => '2017-10-28',
        'phase' => 'Definition',
        'foodstyle' => null,
        'workout_id' => 9
    ],
    2 => [
        'day_date' => '2017-10-29',
        'phase' => 'Definition',
        'foodstyle' => 'DeloadStart',
        'workout_id' => 8
    ],
    3 => [
        'day_date' => '2017-10-30',
        'phase' => 'Definition6',
        'foodstyle' => 'DeloadStart',
        'workout_id' => null
    ],
    4 => [
        'day_date' => '2017-10-31',
        'phase' => 'Definition1',
        'foodstyle' => 'DeloadStart1',
        'workout_id' => 10
    ],
    5 => [
        'day_date' => '2017-11-01',
        'phase' => 'Definition1',
        'foodstyle' => 'DeloadStart1',
        'workout_id' => null
    ],
    6 => [
        'day_date' => '2017-11-02',
        'phase' => null,
        'foodstyle' => null,
        'workout_id' => 11
    ],
    7 => [
        'day_date' => '2017-11-03',
        'phase' => null,
        'foodstyle' => 'DeloadStart2',
        'workout_id' => null
    ],
    8 => [
        'day_date' => '2017-11-04',
        'phase' => 'Definition2',
        'foodstyle' => 'DeloadStart2',
        'workout_id' => 12
    ],
    9 => [
        'day_date' => '2017-11-05',
        'phase' => 'Definition2',
        'foodstyle' => null,
        'workout_id' => null
    ],
    10 => [
        'day_date' => '2017-11-06',
        'phase' => 'Definition',
        'foodstyle' => null,
        'workout_id' => 13
    ],
    11 => [
        'day_date' => '2017-11-07',
        'phase' => 'Definition',
        'foodstyle' => 'DeloadStart9',
        'workout_id' => null
    ],
    12 => [
        'day_date' => '2017-11-08',
        'phase' => 'Definition3',
        'foodstyle' => 'DeloadStart9',
        'workout_id' => 14
    ],
    13 => [
        'day_date' => '2017-11-09',
        'phase' => null,
        'foodstyle' => 'DeloadStart9',
        'workout_id' => null
    ],
    14 => [
        'day_date' => '2017-11-10',
        'phase' => 'Definition',
        'foodstyle' => 'DeloadStart9',
        'workout_id' => 15
    ],
    15 => [
        'day_date' => '2017-11-11',
        'phase' => 'Definition',
        'foodstyle' => 'DeloadStart9',
        'workout_id' => null
    ],
];
```

HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            table {
                font-family: arial, sans-serif;
                border-collapse: collapse;
                width: 100%;
            }

            td, th {
                border: 1px solid #dddddd;
                text-align: left;
                padding: 8px;
                text-align: center;
            }
            .btn {
                border: none;
                color: white;
                padding: 7px 14px;
                font-size: 10px;
                cursor: pointer;
            }
            a {
                text-decoration:  none;
            }

            .success {background-color: #4CAF50;} /* Green */
            .success:hover {background-color: #46a049;}

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Def</th>
                <th>Delode</th>
                <th>Id</th>
            </tr>
            <?php
            $phase = $foodStyle = $workout = '';
            $last_key = end(array_keys($result));
            foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?= $value['day_date'] ?></td>

                    <!-- For Phase HTML-->
                    <?php if ($value['phase'] == null) { ?>
                        <td>-</td>
                    <?php } else if ($phase != $value['phase']) { ?>
                        <td style="border-bottom: none;">
                            <a href="http://localhost/grid/test.php?phase=<?= $value['phase'] ?>&start-data=<?= $value['day_date'] ?>&end-date="><?= $value['phase'] ?></a>
                        </td>    
                        <?php
                        $phase = $value['phase'];
                    } else {
                        ?>
                        <?php if ($key == $last_key) { ?>
                            <td style="border-top: none;"></td>
                        <?php } else { ?>
                            <td style="border: none;"></td>
                        <?php } ?>    
                    <?php } ?>  

                    <!-- For FoodStyle HTML-->    
                    <?php if ($value['foodstyle'] == null) { ?>
                        <td>-</td>
                    <?php } elseif ($foodStyle != $value['foodstyle']) { ?>
                        <td style="border-bottom: none;">
                            <a href="http://localhost/grid/test.php?foodstyle=<?= $value['foodstyle'] ?>&start-data=<?= $value['day_date'] ?>&end-date="><?= $value['foodstyle'] ?></a>
                        </td>    
                        <?php
                        $foodStyle = $value['foodstyle'];
                    } else {
                        ?>
                        <?php if ($key == $last_key) { ?>
                            <td style="border-top: none;"></td>
                        <?php } else { ?>
                            <td style="border: none;"></td>
                        <?php } ?>
                    <?php } ?>    

                    <!-- For Workout Id HTML-->  
                    <?php if ($value['workout_id'] == null) { ?>
                        <td>
                            <a href="http://localhost/grid/test.php?workout_id=<?= $value['workout_id'] ?>&start-data=<?= $value['day_date'] ?>&end-date="> <button class="btn success">  + </button> </a> 
                        </td>
                    <?php } elseif ($workout != $value['workout_id']) { ?>
                        <td style="border-bottom: none;">
                            <a href="http://localhost/grid/test.php?workout_id=<?= $value['workout_id'] ?>&start-data=<?= $value['day_date'] ?>&end-date="><button class="btn success"> <?= $value['workout_id'] ?></button></a> 
                        </td>    
                        <?php
                        $workout = $value['workout_id'];
                    } else {
                        ?>
                        <?php if ($key == $last_key) { ?>
                            <td style="border-top: none;"></td>
                        <?php } else { ?>
                            <td style="border: none;"></td>
                        <?php } ?>
                    <?php } ?>
                </tr>
            <?php } ?>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Output :

[image]

As per the image I want href link like http://localhost/grid/test.php?phase=Definition&start-data=2017-10-27&end-date=2017-10-29 when I click on row 'Definition' of column 'Def' and same for all column. Also I want row 'Definition' in center from all combine column.

Any help would be appreciated.